# filed i539, what to do next?

Tags: visas

my i94 is only valid until July30, 2020. I filed a i539 last June 17, 2020.. I am planning to go back home on October 2nd. Question: Am I good to go back home without waiting for the approval of my i539? or do I need to wait for the approval and do the biometrics? will my tourist visa be voided if I did not do the biometrics? Can I still come back here in the US in the future without any problems?

Answer (score 4):

> Am I good to go back home without waiting for the approval of my i539?
> or do I need to wait for the approval and do the biometrics?

You are good go leave the US while your I-539 is pending. You do not need to wait for I-539 approval or biometrics. Your I-539 will be automatically abandoned.

> will my tourist visa be voided if I did not do the biometrics?

Your visa will not be voided if you leave the US while your timely-filed, non-frivolous I-539 is pending (i.e. before a decision is made on it). See [9 FAM 302.1-9(B)(1)](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM030201.html#M302_1_9_B_1)(c)(4)(b):

> [...] In addition, if an alien departs after the date on the Form I-94
> passes, but before his or her application for extension or change of
> status has been decided by USCIS, they must be subject to a blanket
> exemption from INA 222(g), if the application was filed in a "timely
> manner" and is "nonfrivolous" in nature. [...]

> Can I still come back here in the US in the future without any
> problems?

As always, there is no guarantee that you will be able to enter the US on any particular trip.